# how to position an image on another image if the another image is too wide

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
     #superdown{
         position :relative;
         right: 10px;
         top: 10px;
     }

     #down{
       position: absolute;
       top: 10px;
       right :10px;
     }
   </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="superdown"> 
    <img src="http://images4.alphacoders.com/177/177506.jpg">
    <div id="down">
      <img id="yes" src="http://img.wallpaperstock.net:81/hi%2c-loser-wallpapers_17839_1024x768.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviousy, my background image is too large so i needed to scroll my horizontal bar to view full of it. I wan my my pink picture to be 10px from top and 10px from right of my background picture.But it seems according to the browser that the px I set.I want the pink image to be at the top right, how?Sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are looking like this :- [**DEMO**](http://tinkerbin.com/dNyxftT1)

Just give the `position:absolute;` to **Parent Div**

Comment: ya, i know, but i wan a full view of the alien picture, this does nt show the full view

Comment: yes, but when u see the real image http://images4.alphacoders.com/177/177506.jpg  and compare to that one the left part of the head are gone

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, when you use `position: relative;` on the #superdown image, the absolute positioning of the #down image is based on the browser's boundaries. One way to fix this is to set #superdown to `position: absolute;`, although I'm of course not certain if that won't mess up other things in your page.